# whether sharepoint site collection can be mapped to more than one content db

Tags: sharepoint

I have mapped seperate content db(200 gb) to a site collection. Now it is going to exceed 200 gb. So can i map another content db to it.

If so, then how to do it. Whether site collection will show data's from two content db, if I map another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move some of the data to a new site collection and a new content database. Site collections cannot span content databases.